# Java--Difficulty Using return

Tags: java

I am new at java, and am having difficulties using the return statement. The teacher is asking to create methods according to the descriptions given of which I'm having trouble creating a get statement: "public Exam()", the description is "initialize the instance variables: the count as 0, the total as 0, and scores as "". (2 Pts)". And the other is "public int getCount()", the description is "return the value of count (1 Pts)". Simplified its as follows, according to how I interpreted the instructions.

```
public class Exam{

    public Exam()
    {
        int count = 0;
        int total = 0;
        String scores = "";
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Compiling it as is gives an error that says that it doesn't recognize symbol while indicating at the "count" of "return count", and the other methods depend on variables in Exam() and updating them.

Edit: Since it got voted down so quickly, I'll gander a guess and say that it's probably something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't recognize it, and neither should it.  You haven't defined `count` anywhere except within your constructor.

This isn't an issue with the `return` statement, this is an issue with scope.

The short answer here is you can *declare* them outside of your constructor, and *instantiate* them inside of it.  This will work, since your variable has now been defined at a level that both your constructor and your getter can use it at.

```
public class Exam {
    private int count;
    private int total;
    private String scores;

    public Exam() {
        count = 0;
        total = 0;
        scores = "";
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

The slightly more involved answer is straighforward; this is *why* it works.

A variable defined within a block (denoted by curly braces) is said to be within scope of that block and all other blocks contained in it.

This means that your class and all of its associated methods have some sort of scope within it.

Now, by declaring your fields at the class level, any method (or constructor) may use these variables.

If you declare them within your constructor, only the constructor is aware of those variables' existence, and other methods won't be privy to the data that they contain.